# High Dimensional Data Clustering

Tags: c#, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

What are the best clustering algorithms to use in order to cluster data with more than 100 dimensions (sometimes even 1000). I would appreciate if you know any implementation in C, C++ or especially C#.

Comment: About how many data points, how many clusters so you have ? Do some points have known class labels ? How are the clusters to be used ? There's no "best algorithm" for such a huge range of possibilities. Perhaps read the top half of [Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), then ask again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends heavily on your data. See **curse of dimensionality** for common problems. Recent research (Houle et al.) showed that you can't really go by the numbers. There may be thousands of dimensions and the data clusters well, and of course there is even one-dimensional data that just doesn't cluster. It's mostly a matter of signal-to-noise.
This is why for example clustering of TF-IDF vectors works rather well, in particular with cosine distance.

But the key point is that you *first* need to understand the nature of your data. You then can pick appropriate distance functions, weights, parameters and ... algorithms.

In particular, you also need to know *what* constitutes a cluster for you. There are many definitions, in particular for high-dimensional data. They may be in subspaces, they may or may not be arbitrarily rotated, they may overlap or not (k-means for example, doesn't allow overlaps or subspaces).

Answer (score 0):

well i know something called vector quantization, its a nice algorithem to cluster stuf with many dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

i've used k-means on data with 100's dimensions, it is very common so i'm sure theres an implementation in any language, worst case scenario - it is very easy to implement by your self.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth trying some dimensionality reduction techniques like Principle Component Analysis or an auto-associative neural net before you try to cluster it. It can turn a huge problem into a much smaller one.

After that, go k-means or mixture of gaussians.

Comment: Could you give me some information about the neural net approach? But I suppose it must be trained?

Comment: This is probably old and dead now but I just saw this. Yes, as with any net you'll need to train it. The idea is that you use an interior layer of N nodes, with N << Dims, then you train it to reproduce the input data on the output nodes. In doing so, you are forcing the net to discard some of the data. Minimizing the difference between the input and output will ensure that the most informative data is retained. Example: inputs (mom's height, dad's height, dad's eyecolor); outputs(child's height), inner nodes 2. During training, the weights for eye color go to zero because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The EM-tree and K-tree algorithms in the [LMW-tree](https://github.com/cmdevries/LMW-tree) project can cluster high dimensional problems like this. It is implemented in C++ and supports many different representations.

We have novel algorithms clustering binary vectors created by LSH / Random Projections, or anything else that emits binary vectors that can be compared via Hamming distance for similarity.